# How will I fix this so that I can have different thumbnails in every web pages?

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I'm new in making website, I searched on how to put an open graph, but I encountered a problem where I can only put 1 thumbnail for the website. Let's say I have 4 Navigation Menu (Home, About, Contact, Resources), what I want is that every tab has its own thumbnail.

What happened is that, For example: '<meta property="og:image"content="fb-photo1.png"/>', that fb-photo1.png will appear every time I linked my Home, About, Contact or Resources page in fb.

What i want is to have a photo in each menu, fb-photo1.png = Home, fb-photo2.png = About, fb-photo3.png = Contact, fb-photo4.png = Resources.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script>
    window.location.href('https://www.org.com/')
  </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Primary Meta Tags -->
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <meta name="title" content="title">
    meta name="description" content="content">

<!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="website-url">
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="og:description" content="desc...">
<meta property="og:image"content="fb.png"/>

<!-- Twitter -->
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="website-url">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="title">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="desc...">
<meta property="twitter:image"content="twitter.png"/>


<base href="/">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="SFwVlHE2qbo3_JQG4bT1aoXNAhNkSqLereGQYYBXnFg" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

> Blockquote

What happened is that when I link to fb any of the pages, the thumbnail is the same, I cant find solution on how to tweak the code so that I will have different thumbnail for every pages in my website. I tried this code, and tried other stuff online, but no solution worked.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have four tabs? Can you show your code for that?

Comment: Let me use "Navigation Menu" instead. I use angularjs, so for every page I use 1 html, 1 css and 1 ts file.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2+?

Comment: Angular 2!!! sori got confused and exchanged the framework w/ my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's built-in [Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) Service and it's `updateTag` method for this.

You propbably are using Open Graph for your landing page. In this case just leave a baseline of meta tags. In every sub-component or route that needs adjustments to the tags, just import the meta service in every component and update tags as such:

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser'

export class Component {

    constructor(
        private readonly router: Router,
        private readonly meta: Meta
    ) {
        meta.updateTag({
                property: 'og:url',
                content: 'website-url'
        })
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you would need to do this in every component / route that needs adjustments.

Another thing to keep in mind, is that the updated tag values stay until removed or updated, which is usually not important for the use of OpenGraph or SEO.

Comment: Yes, I did this on my landing page. Thank u so much for this! Will try this. Just a few Qs. I'm new in Angular 2, what if in my TS file,  Im already using " constructor(private router:Router) { }", what other way can I have both router and meta inside constructor?

Comment: I edited the example in my answer. Basically you can add every dependency or service you need as parameters, separated by a comma, to the constructor.